# How to prove that the following is Cauchy?

Tags: cauchy-sequences

So I have to prove that the following is a Cauchy sequence by definition:

$|u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}|\leq \frac{1}{2}|u_{n+1}-u_n|$.

I know that, $$|u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}|\leq \frac{1}{2^n} |u_2-u_1|$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: See these: [link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164254/a-n1-a-n-leq-frac12-a-n-a-n-1-prove-a-n-is-cauchy?rq=1) or [link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070528/prove-that-a-n1-a-n-leq-frac12a-n-a-n-1-implies-a-n-b?noredirect=1&lq=1) or more generally [link 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677423/proof-contraction-mapping-and-cauchy-sequence)

Comment: Hint: $\vert u_m-u_n\vert\leq\sum_{k=n}^{m-1}\vert u_{k+1}-u_k\vert$. (Also, justify this inequality!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $m \ge n \ge 2$, note that

\begin{align}
|u_m - u_n| &= |u_m - u_{m - 1} + u_{m - 1} - \cdots + u_{n + 1} - u_n| \\
& \le |u_m - u_{m - 1}| + \cdots + |u_{n + 1} - u_n| \\
& \le \frac{1}{2^{m-2}}|u_2 - u_1| + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}|u_2 - u_1| \\
& = |u_2 - u_1|\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{m - 2}}\right) \\
& \le |u_2 - u_1|\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} + \cdots \right) \\
& = \frac{|u_2 - u_1|}{2^{n - 2}}.
\end{align}

Can you conclude now?

Comment: Thank you so much!!